# How to stop Propagation on Double Click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling, dom-events

Consider this component:

```
<Card onClick={openWindowHandler}>
  <Editable onDoubleClick={enableInputHandler} />
</Card>
```

What I want to achieve is to stop event propagation, **only** when `onDoubleClick` event is dispatched, so the `openWindowHandler` function is not called. However, `onClick` will fire before `onDoubleClick`!

I can distinguish which event type was called by applying `_.debounce` function, but by that time, the event was already dispatched, so there is no way to call `stopPropagation()`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  delayedCallback = _.debounce(function (event) {
    if (event.type === 'dblclick') {
      // too late to call event.stopPropagation()
    } else {
      // continue
    }
  }, 250)

  handleClick = (event) => {
    event.persist()
    this.delayedCallback(event)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Card onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <Editable onDoubleClick={this.handleClick} />
      </Card>
    )
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

**EDIT:**
The single click on `<Editable />` element should be bubbled to parents causing `openWindowHandler` call.

Comment: You have an ergonomical issue: on your card you should have a onLongClick props. The user will be not messed by your single or double click.

Comment: The Card is not the issue here. It can be any other component. The problem is havig component with onDoubleClick inside another component with onClick event. <Editable /> should be somehow able to stop propagating the event to it's parents.

Comment: add on editable : onClick={(e) => {e.stopPropagation()}}, it's possible that it affect onDoubleClick, but try it :).

Comment: I can't :( The single click should be propagated to it's parent, only the double click should suppress propagation.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
// This will return a event
function clickHandlerModule() {
    var clickCount = 0;
    var timer = null;
    var delay = 250;
    return function(event) {
        clickCount++;
        if(clickCount === 1){
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('SINGLE CLICK');
                clickCount = 0;
            }, delay);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            console.log('DOUBLE CLICK');
            clickCount = 0;
        }
    }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.clickHandler = clickHandlerModule()
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <Card onClick={this.clickHandler}>
        <Editable />
      </Card>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Sample {
   clickCount = 0;

   onItemClick() {
        let isDoubleClick = false;
        this.clickCount++;
        if (this.clickCount === 1) {
            setTimeout(() => {
               if (this.clickCount > 1) {
                isDoubleClick = true;
                console.log('dblclick');
               }
               this.clickCount = 0;
               if (!isDoubleClick) {
                console.log('click');
               }
           }, 250);
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <Card (click)="onItemClick()">
    <Editable (dblclick)="SomeMethodForDblClick()" />
  </Card>
```

So you can write some methods for ***click && dblClick*** events at **cart.component** and use ***dblclick*** for **editable.component** with no conflicts

P.S. yeah, I'm using angular, sorry for syntax:)